# Install pygame in anaconda

Tags: python

I have anaconda on Ubuntu 14.04. I want to install the `pygame` module with anaconda. I already run `sudo apt-get install python-pygame`, but this only works on python, not in anaconda.

Answer (score 4):

I realize I am quite late to the party but here is what worked for me if anyone needs it. Ubuntu 14.04 64-bit with Anaconda 2.3.0 installed.

Install binstar:

```
conda install binstar
```

You get a response like: The 'binstar' conda package has been renamed to 'anaconda-client'. Please run: conda install anaconda-client.
So run:

```
conda install anaconda-client
```

Then search for the pygame package on anaconda.org:

```
anaconda search -t conda pygame
```

You get a list of pygame packages available at anaconda.org. Select a package for your distribution e.g. **tlatorre/pygame** is for Linux 64-bit.
To install it use:

```
conda install -c https://conda.binstar.org/tlatorre pygame
```

Once done, `import pygame` should work.

Credit: Answer by cohdez on
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29137369/installing-pygame-module-in-anaconda-mac

Answer (score 1):

Use this code at Terminal:
    conda install binstar
    conda clean --lock
    conda install anaconda-client

Search for appropriate package at:

anaconda search -t conda pygame

For Python 3 use the following

```
conda install -c https://conda.binstar.org/kne pygame
```

for Ubuntu this would work

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same problem and am looking for the same answer. Sadly, I didn't find an answer to install pygame with anaconda. What I did find is an alternate solution. You have to change your path like so:

Open terminal and run

```
echo $PATH
```

then you will see:

```
/home/username/anaconda/bin:/usr/lib/etcetcetc..
```

Now, copy this from the `:` to the end (excluding `:`). Then, run

```
PATH=/home/username/anaconda/bin:/usr/lib/etcetcetc..
```

This will make the terminal use the default python and pygame will work. This is not permanent. When you close the terminal, this is automatically changed.